# Single custom post type page redirect to 404 page

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error

Helo,

i am trying to convert some posts to new custom post type. Then i get an error.

Special at my wordpress-installation:

I have categories and pages with the same slug. For example:

- /state/ (page)
- /state/ (category)

The posts have the format /state/city/

Permalinks-Setting: /%category%/%postname%/

I would like to keep this format

**My code in functions.php:**

```
// Custom Post Type function
function astra_custom_post_types() {
    // Basic session post type
    register_post_type('city', array(
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,        
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields'),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => '/%category%',
        'with_front' => true,
        'pages' => false,
        'feeds' => false,
    ),
    'labels' => array( 'name' => 'city', 'add_new_item' => 'Add new city', 'edit_item' => 'Edit city', 'all_items' => 'All cities', 'sinuglar_name' => 'city', 'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar'),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
    ));
}
// Include the function in the Astra theme
add_action('init', 'astra_custom_post_types');

/**
 * add category slug to city post links
 * @param $post_link
 * @param $id
 */
 function my_commmunity_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'city' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
        if( !empty($terms) ){
            return str_replace( '%category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_community_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

The problem is also that since registering the new Custom Post Type, when I call /state/ I get the category content and not the /state/ page content.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Re-save permalinks
- flush_rewrite_rules( true ); in functions.php
- delete htaccess completely and let wordpress create it again

I noticed that generally all pages/posts in /folder/ format return a 404 error. In contrast, all content in a subdirectory such as /folder/my-page/ display the content correctly.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: did you flush permalinks via settings? Using `flush_rewrite_rules` in code isn't a silver bullet solution to rewrite rules as when it runs and when your CPT are registered can be significant. Also `post_type_link` only filters the URL on output, it does not influence rewrite rules, e.g. you can have it do this: `return "google.com";` and your posts would still have the same URL, but every hyperlink on the frontend would say google.com. If you had changed the rewrite rules to be correct the `post_link` filter would be unnecessary

Comment: Yes. i flushed the permalinks (see my post) manually. Thanks for the tip about the post_type_link. So it's because of the rewrites themselves. I'm afraid it's somehow because of the duplicate slugs. Could that be?

Comment: that definitely contributes to it, but that's an ordering problem, you can test for that via a rewrite rule tester plugin by typing in the URL and seeing which rules apply and specifically the order they appear in. There are several rewrite rule testing tools in the .org plugin repo

Comment: I have even had one of the rewrite tester tools installed. Thanks for the tip to enter the URL there. Had not seen the function at all.

Now when I enter one of the URLs (CPT) I get the following output:

Rule Rewrite Source
(.+?)/(.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$ index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&stadt=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3] stadt
(.+?)/?$ index.php?category_name=$matches[1] stadt
(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$ index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2] page
(.+?)/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$ index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3] post

Comment: That means I would have to change the order for the rewrites in the htaccess file or add rewrites in general???

Comment: HTAccess has nothing to do with this. That file is only relevant here if you were seeing a generic Apache 404 or something that wasn't WordPress. If you are seeing a WordPress 404 from your theme then ignore HTAccess. HTAccess is just there to tell Apache how to route requests to WordPress. Also you can edit your question, put code there not in comments